# QTime behaving different in linux and windows platforms

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, qtime

I have same Qt code which runs in both linux and windows . But it is acting different in each case.
In linux it is behaving correct , but while in windows it is not.

[image: In linux it is behaving as follows]

[image: In Windows it is behaving as follows]

you can see that in windows platform it is returning null string and in linux platform it is behaving as expected. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Qt in both cases?

Comment: What is `strTemp` if you output it with `qDebug` or similar?  Values displayed by debuggers (as I assume is the case here) can be misleading on highly optimized code.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] as text not images

Comment: I'm surprised the Linux version works: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#QTime-1

Comment: @AlanBirtles After initializing  QTime time(0,0); it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor of [`QTime`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#QTime-1) produces an `invalid` time, most operations on an invalid time will fail or return another invalid time. Calling `addSecs` still leaves you with an invalid time and calling [`toString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString) on an invalid time returns an empty string.

To construct a `QTime` of midnight you need to use:

```
QTime time(0,0);
```